# Поиск неточного значения списка в другом списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, список

Есть 2 списка

```
a = ['http', 'www']
b = ['prelest', 'kakaya', 'je', 'eti', 'https', 'listi', 'ili www.daje']
```

Требуется перебрать список `b` отыскав неточные (ну и точные, конечно, тоже) соответствия из списка `a`. В данном конкретном случае, например, должно быть 2 соответствия. Сейчас я делаю это так

```
for i in c:
    for a in l:
        if i in a:
            print(i)
```

Но перфекционист внутри меня говорит, что тратить на такую операцию 4 строки - от лукавого; и я верю, в таком умном языке как `python` должен быть оператор который сделает это в одну строку (ну типа, `filter`, `lambda` и прочие `any`). Собсно вопрос: Подскажите, пожалуйста, более короткий (и, может даже, более правильный) вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сначала переименуем списки:

```
items = b
search = a
```

---

простой и понятный `list comprehension`:

```
In [27]: [i for i in items for s in search if s in i]
Out[27]: ['https', 'ili www.daje']
```

`filter()` + `any()` + `lambda`:

```
In [37]: list(filter(lambda x: any(s for s in search if s in x), items))
Out[37]: ['https', 'ili www.daje']
```

с использованием регулярных выражений:

```
In [46]: import re

In [47]: pat = '(?:{})'.format('|'.join(search))

In [48]: [i for i in items if re.search(pat, i)]
Out[48]: ['https', 'ili www.daje']
```

Comment: Как же сложно неискушенному уму понять что тут написано :)

Comment: @whoknow, лично мне первый вариант кажется более читабельным...

Comment: Ну да, я листы назвал нормально (больше чем 1 буква) и стало понятно что там происходит